# removeClass("disabled") in JQuery doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="add_argument_button" class="btn btn-default disabled">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="remove_class" onclick="remove_disabled();">
    remove
</button>
```

And js function:

```
function remove_disabled(){
    $("#add_argument_button").removeClass("disabled);
}
```

It works and when I click on second button the first button is not de facto disabled and I can click on it. But view of button and cursor stay as disabled. I think, that I need reload first button. Why we can resolve this problem?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting; currently you're missing a `"` that may be a typo in transcribing your code, given that it works at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes at the end of your removeClass statement.

```
$("#add_argument_button").removeClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to disable the first button?

```js
function remove_disabled(){
 $("#add_argument_button").removeClass('disabled');
  $("#add_argument_button").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add_argument_button" class="btn btn-default disabled">
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="remove_class" onclick="remove_disabled();">
remove
</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Its working

```
<body>
    <button type="button" id="add_argument_button" class="btn btn-default disabled">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
</button>
    <button type="button" id="remove_class">
    remove
</button>

    <div id="logbefore"></div>
    <div id="logafter"></div>
</body>


// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
    $("#logbefore").text($("#add_argument_button").attr('class'));

    $("#add_argument_button").removeClass("disabled");

    $("#logafter").text($("#add_argument_button").attr('class'));
});
```